# JQuery delay() breaks fadeIn sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to fadeIn elements in header every time you scroll on it, so I created this function:

```
function headerAnimation() {
    if(isScrolledIntoView('.vintage-header')) {
      $('.header-logo, .festival, .atelieru, .konani').each(function(fadeInElem) {
        $(this).css('visibility', 'visible').delay(fadeInElem * 1000).fadeIn(1000);
      });
    }
    if(isScrolledIntoView('#theme')) {
      $('.header-logo, .festival, .atelieru, .konani').each(function() {
        $(this).hide();
      });
    }
}
```

//note: isScrolledIntoView tests if the div is in viewport

Now I set the interval:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    headerAnimationID = setInterval(headerAnimation, 33);
});
```

On first load of page, it works fine, but everytime I will scroll down and then back to header, the elements will fadeIn in incorrect, shuffled order :-( If i setInterval to 4000, it works fine, but it's too long before you can see the first element. How can I solve this?

Comment: Why are you setting `css('visibility', 'visible')`?

Comment: Because I set `visbility: hidden;` to all elements when the document is ready, if anyone has got js turned off, he will see the content

Comment: See the updated answer below.

Comment: not working, divs still don't fadeIn in correct order when I scroll back to header

Comment: Can you post of fiddle of your code?

Comment: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/8hb3z30L/) but function isScrolledIntoView doesn't work properly in fiddle, when you are scrolling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add stop() to the hide function `$(this).stop().hide();` to stop the animation (fadeIn).
Also you can add the checking if the element is in view on scroll so you don't have to fire the function all the time with the interval, only when the user scrolls.

```js
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var $window = $(window),
        docViewTop = $window.scrollTop(),
        docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height(),
        elemTop = $(elem).offset().top,
        elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).outerHeight();
    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

$(window).on("scroll", function () {    
    if (isScrolledIntoView('.vintage-header')) {
        $('.header-logo, .festival, .atelieru, .konani').each(function (fadeInElem) {
            $(this).css('visibility', 'visible').delay(fadeInElem * 1000).fadeIn(1000);
        });
    }
    if (isScrolledIntoView('#theme')) {
        console.log('in');
        $('.header-logo, .festival, .atelieru, .konani').each(function () {
            $(this).stop().hide();
        });
    }
});
```

```css
.vintage-header {
    background: green;
}
#theme {
    background: red;
}
.spacer {
    height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="vintage-header">
    <div class="header-logo">Header Logo</div>
    <div class="festival">festival</div>
    <div class="atelieru">atelieru</div>
    <div class="konani">konani</div>
</div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div id="theme">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem nesciunt libero doloribus nisi suscipit perspiciatis tenetur mollitia vitae incidunt culpa quo tempore dolor animi quidem similique accusamus reprehenderit veniam fuga?</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just do

```
if(isScrolledIntoView('.vintage-header')) {
      $('.header-logo, .festival, .atelieru, .konani').each(function(fadeInElem) {
        $(this).delay(fadeInElem * 1000).fadeIn(1000);
      });
    }
```

And on the DOM ready set `display:none;` to hide.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 if(isScrolledIntoView('.vintage-header')) {
          $('.header-logo, .festival, .atelieru, .konani').each(function(fadeInElem) {
            $(this).delay(fadeInElem * 1000).fadeIn(1000);
          });
        }
```